# Loop through files to retrieve data for solidworks

Tags: vba, loops, solidworks

I have written the following code which works fine when I open one file. However, my knowledge of vba coding is low. I used a for loop in order to open a range of file names output_1 to output_61, but I get the error of "Run-time error '53' File not found". Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the code I have wrote:
Regards,
Jer

```
Dim swApp As Object

Sub main()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
    swApp.ActiveDoc.ActiveView.FrameState = 1
    Dim skPoint As Object

    For i = 1 To 61
        Open "C:\Users\jerry.obrien\Desktop\2MW Blade\Solidworks\output_i.txt" For Input As #1
        Part.SketchManager.Insert3DSketch True
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Input #1, X, Y, Z
            Set skPoint = Part.SketchManager.CreatePoint(X / 1, Y / 1, Z / 1)
        Loop
    Next i
    Close #1

    Part.ShowNamedView2 "*Isometric", 7
    Part.ViewZoomtofit2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to "C:\Users\jerry.obrien\Desktop\2MW Blade\Solidworks\output_" & i & ".txt"

Comment: Sorry but when I run it I get the following error: Run-time error'55' File already open. The loop doesn't seem to be progressing

Comment: Move Close #1  before next i

Comment: Since you are editing the file it should be For Output As #1

Answer (score 0):

Some generic looping stuff

```
 path = "C:\Users\jerry.obrien\Desktop\2MW Blade\Solidworks" & "\" 
 Filename = Dir(path & "*.txt??")

 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
     DoEvents
     debug.? "found "; path & Filename
     Filename = Dir()
         For Each..... 
         Next .....
   Filename = Dir
 Loop
```

Comment: Sorry but it says the path is not found

Comment: fixed. Sorry I goofed up the file name in my original answer

Comment: See if this helps. I am thinking maybe it has to do with the file type?

Comment: `Dim swApp As Object
Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
swApp.ActiveDoc.ActiveView.FrameState = 1
Dim Temp As Object

For i = 1 To 61
Set Temp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 rTemP = "C:\Users\jerry.obrien\Desktop\2MW Blade\Solidworks" & "\" & "output_i.txt" For Input As #1
 Temp.Open (rTemP)

 
Part.SketchManager.Insert3DSketch True
Do While Not EOF(1)
Input #1, X, Y, Z
Set skPoint = Part.SketchManager.CreatePoint(X / 1, Y / 1, Z / 1)
Loop
Next i
Close #1

Part.ShowNamedView2 "*Isometric", 7
Part.ViewZoomtofit2
End Sub` get a syntax error.

Comment: I must be going blind but I cannot see it

Comment: sorry wasnt able to look at this again till this morning. Ill have to look at it some more and figure out the issue. I thought it was as simple as a directory pointing error. I will however add some generic looping through a file logic in my original answer for you though (as your loop only looks at one file not all files in the folder)